# Unable to write in directory Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, permissions

In my server, I get this error message

```
Unable to write in the "/home/company/blog/public/img" directory
```

When I try to upload an image like this in my controller

```
$file = $request->file('img');
        $name = time() . '-' . $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $file->move(public_path() .'/img/', $name);
        $company = company::where('username', $username)->first();
        $company->images()->create(['path' => "/{$name}"]);
```

I know it's about granting permissions I tried

```
chmod 755 /home/company/blog/public/img
```

But it still doesn't work.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Check if the `public_path()` is the right path, print it and give us the output.

Comment: public_path() returns `/home/company/blog/public`

Comment: Use `ls -la` to list the ownership of the folder and include that info in the question

Comment: img has `drwxr-xr-x` this permission

Comment: You should have a look at the owner and group of a directory.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a common case when your server uses different user than you use in console. You can have `www-data` for web server and `user` for console.

`755` means full rights for owner and read+execute for the user's group and others ([read this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/638796/what-is-meaning-of-755-permissions-in-samba-share)). So, when you `chmod 755` as `user`, you grant full access for `user` and no write permission to `www-data`.

You have to change owner of the directory to your server's user. If your server's user is `www-data`, use

`sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /home/company/blog/public/img`

Comment: I already tried that actually, my server's user is `company` and I tried `sudo chown -R company:company /home/company/blog/public/img`

Comment: How did you know that? `ps aux|grep nginx|grep -v grep` shows user for nginx.

Comment: I am using apache

Comment: Well, substitute `nginx` with `httpd`. Whatever. How did you know the user?

Comment: In my terminal I have `company@ubuntu1-01` , I am thinking `company` is the user?

Comment: This is your terminal user. Apache can use another one. Launch `ps aux | egrep '(apache|httpd)'` and see it.

Comment: I tried running `ps aux | grep -v root | grep apache | cut -d\  -f1 | sort | uniq` and got `company` and `www-data` so I think `www-data` is the default user for apache

Comment: You got `company` since it is `company` that launches this command :) This  simple command has its process as well. You should add `| grep -v grep` to ignore the command.